# Windows PowerShell how to handle colon character that stops output from printing to screen

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

This is a classic example of "don't know what terms to Google because I don't know the terms".

When I use a command in PowerShell (in this case, Windows PowerShell (1.14.2281.0)), sometimes all of the output goes to the screen so I can scroll up and down, and sometimes the output prints just enough to fill up the screen, followed by a colon (see image).
[image]

I can't get out of this "colon" mode.  There are two keys that I found that do anything:  the down arrow scrolls down, and the "space" button goes to the next screen, but when I get to the end of the printout, I'm in "end" and I'm stuck there.
[image]

How can I toggle this mode?  How can I not be stuck when I reach the end?  How can I... do *anything* in this mode besides what I've already described?

Comment: What OS are you on? What command are you running to get this output? It looks like a Githhub call. You can avoid the screen output by sending to results to Out-GridView or to Notepad for review. I've never seen this issue before and don't have any PS that old.

Comment: I suspect `1.14.2281.0` is your Windows Terminal version. Could you run `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` so we can understand what version of PowerShell you're running and update the question with the output.

Comment: Hi @jfrmilner. PS version is 5.1.19041.1682. Windows 10. BitBucket call.  With that said, I get this colon thing all the time -- have for years, on many different OSes and versions of PowerShell.  I've just never asked about it.  It reminds me of Vim.